# can't see user input in html.php form when css page is linked

Tags: html, css

I have an html.php file that without any css renders as expected. But as soon as I add the following CSS none of the values in `input` fields (text, checks, etc.) can be seen. But I can highlight a text field for example and copy and paste its contents fine, so I know the fields contain values.

I have dinked around changing background and font colors in case there is some problem there but nothing seems to alter this behavior. Something else quirky that likely seems to be linked to this problem, is when I click on a text field input the (flashing) cursor is visible and the right size, but as I begin typing and the cursor moves across the text box, it changes to a very small cursor size. Weird. Again, no CSS and the html.php form page works as expected.

Can someone look at the CSS and let me know if there is some glaring issue that could explain the weirdness I am experiencing?

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
fieldset {
  max-width: 900px;
}

.formContent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 55px;

  background-color:  #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  font: bold 14px sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}

.formContent .formRowDiv {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 315px;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
}

.formContent .formRowDiv label span {
  /*display: block;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  /*box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);*/
  /*padding: 12px 18px;*/
  /*border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;*/
}

.formContent input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  padding: 12px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  color:  #5f5f5f;
}

.formContent input[type=checkbox],
.formContent input[type=radio] {
  box-shadow: none;
  width: auto;
}

.formContent input[type=text]{
  height: 10px;
  /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  color: orange;
}

.formContent .radioButtons > div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.formContent .radioButtons label span {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color:  #5f5f5f;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.formContent .textInputShort {
  width: 75px;
}

html {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**EDIT to include HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <title>Site Details</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
...
?>
  <h1 id="heading">Site Details</h1>

  <div id="clearPageDiv">
    <p><a href="index2.php">
      <input id="clearPage" class="button" type="button" name="clearPage" value="Clear Page">
      <input type="submit" value="Retreive Site Details">
    </a></p>
  </div><!-- closes clearPageDiv -->

  <!--fieldset id="Site:"-->
    <!--legend>Site:</legend-->
    <div id="formContentDiv">
      <form class="formContent" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span>Site Id:</span>
            <input id="siteId" name="siteId" class="textInputShort" type="text" maxlength="" $value=""> 
            <script>
              siteId.value = <?php echo json_encode( $siteId ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span>Site Name:</span>
            <input id="siteName" name="siteName" class="textInput" type="text" maxlength="" $value="test"> 
            <!--input type="submit" value="Retreive"-->
            <script>
              siteName.value = <?php echo json_encode( $siteName ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="formRowDiv">
          <label>
            <span># HSPA BBUs:</span>
            <input id="numHspaBbu" name="numHspaBbu" class="textInputShort" type="text" maxlength="" $value=""> 
            <script>
              numHspaBbu.value = <?php echo json_encode( $numHspaBbu ); ?>;
            </script>
          </label>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div><!-- close mainWrap -->
  <!-- /fieldset -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the html this css is applied to.

Comment: you should use the debugger tools in your browser (Inspect Element in FF or Inspect in Chrome), there you can see the styles applied and the styles overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "height" in:

```
    .formContent input[type=text]{
  height: 10px;
  /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  color: orange;
}
```

so it became:

```
.formContent input[type=text]{

  /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  color: orange;
}
```

Comment: well that did it. I previously changed 10px to 20px without effect, so I kept trying other settings, not realizing that 20px height was still not enough height to show field data. But now I have to ferret out why my text input boxes are left big and ugly. Looks like a padding issue but commenting out all padding attributes changes nothing. CSS can be a web of evil.

Comment: why not use bootstrap? it's great for start and you can customize it anyway you want.

Comment: ya know I just scrapped that css file in the end, which I lifted from another page, and spun one up from scratch. Now everything is a lot simpler, rendering the appearance I was looking for.